# Does $K( (\oplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\ell^1_n)_{\ell^p})$ have the weak Phillips property?

Tags: banach-spaces

A Banach space $X$ has the *weak Phillips property* if the canonical projection $X^{***}\to X^{*}$ is sequentially weak$^{*}$-weak continuous [[FreedmanÜlger2000](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-00-05703-8), [Ülger2001](https://doi.org/10.4064/cm87-2-1)].

Let $1<p<\infty$ and $E = (\oplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\ell^1_n)_{\ell^p}$ be the $\ell^p$ direct sum of $(\ell^1_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

**Question:** Does the space of compact operators $K(E)$ have the weak Phillips property?

Comment: For the records: $K(E)$ is an M-ideal in $B(E)$ by Corollary VI.5.4 in [https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0789.46011] referenced by Dirk Werner in his answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. This is essentially an unpublished result due to Hermann Pfitzner, see III.3.6 and III.3.7 in *$M$-ideals in Banach spaces and Banach algebras* by P. Harmand, W. Werner and myself ([Zbl 0789.46011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0789.46011)) along with the fact that $K(E)$ is an $M$-ideal in its bidual $L(E)$.

Comment: Professor Werner, thank you very much.