# A list of properties of $(\bigoplus \ell^1_n)_{\ell^p}$, $1<p<\infty$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The Banach space $E=(\bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\ell^1_n)_{\ell^p}$ for $1<p<\infty$ shows up in various places in the literature to construct counterexamples. The purpose of this post is to accumulate the properties of this space in a single page.

I have made a short list for a start. (My question is) Please write down in the answers or comments below the other properties that are known to you, so I can add them to this list for everyone's (esp. students', beginners', and amateurs') benefit.

Thanks very much in advance.

- $E$ has a basis, so have the approximation property (AP).
- $E$ is reflexive but not superreflexive, since $\ell^1$ is finitely representable on $E$.
- $K(E)^* = E \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}} E^*$ since $E$ has AP and RNP.
  Also,$\hspace{4mm}B(E) = \big( E \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}} E^* \big)^* = K(E)^{**}$.
- $K(E)^*$ has RNP [[Ruess1984](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-0208(08)71467-1)]. As a result, $K(E)$ contains no copy of $\ell^1$.
- $K(E)$ is an M-ideal in $B(E)$ [[HWW1993](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/werner99/mideals.html), Corollary 6.5.4]. Thus, every closed subspace of $K(E)$ has property (V) [[HWW1993](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/werner99/mideals.html), Corollary 3.3.7].
- $ap(K(E)) = \{0\}$ since $E$ has AP [[DuncanUlger1992](https://doi.org/10.1216/rmjm/1181072699), Proposition 3.3].
- $wap(K(E)) = K(E)^*$ since $E$ is reflexive, see e.g. [[DalesLau2005](https://doi.org/10.1090/memo/0836), p.54]. Equivalently, $K(E)$ is Arens regular. This could be derived from the fact that $K(E)$ has property (V), since every Banach algebra with property (V) is Arens regular.
- $B(E)$ is not Arens regular [[Daws2004](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024609303003072), Corollary 2].
- $B(E)$ does not have property (V), since every Banach algebra with property (V) is Arens regular.
- $B(E)$ contains a complemented copy of $\ell^1$ [[Kania2013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2012.12.017)].
- $B(E)$ is not a Grothendieck space [[Kania2013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2012.12.017)].

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410580/does-k-oplus-n-1-infty-ell1-n-ellp-have-the-weak-phillips-prope